# how to use HomePod mini as a mic for Mac mini

Tags: homepod

I have a HomePod mini.
I want to use it as a mic for my Mac mini.
How do I do this?
I want to use it for Siri and google meet.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> It cannot be used as a microphone and DOES NOT show up under input in the sound settings.

https://reddit.com/r/macmini/comments/k1b271/limitations_of_using_a_homepod_or_homepod_mini_as/gdngtrm

It acts as an AirPlay receiver like Apple TV, not a Bluetooth device like AirPods.